# If there is a violation in magnetic interaction b/w two non parellel current carrying wires

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics

when two current carrying wires are put near, there is a magnetic interaction b/w the wires. if they are kept parellel, they'll follow newton's 3rd law. i want to ask that if they are not kept parallel, **will there be any type of violation in newton's 3rd law?** doesn't the law of conservation of momentum holds here?

Comment: Can anyone answer my question, please...